# Custom Docker image fails on another machine (psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name to address)

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Absolutely new to Docker and Postgres (I know they're not related in a tight way, but please read on).

I have a simple python script (not a Django project; not a Kivy project - just a *.py* file). It fetches something and writes it into the Postgres db (using `psycopg2`). On my (Windows 10) machine, (after a million trial and errors to get this working) it works. So when I `docker-compose up` the whole project, it does the thing it's supposed to do, and writes it into the Postgres db. After that, when I `Docker push` the resulting image to the DockerHub, then `Docker pull` on to a totally unrelated Linux Azure VM, it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/file00.py", line 19, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "zedb" to address: Name or service not known
```

`zedb` is the name of the Postgres database service in the Docker-compose file (I've pasted it below).

I know I've not something right, but I am not sure what it is.

DockerFile for the script (it's pretty much the default template that VSCode gives you):

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:latest

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "file00.py"]
```

The db part does not contain a Dockerfile, but an `init.sql` file that creates the table needed for the script to write into. It is mounted from local to the Postgres image from the docker-compose file. From what I understand, if the container fails/shuts down somehow, the data in the tables is retained (volume persistence) and when the container is spun up again, the table is created. Here's what in the `init.sql` file:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pt (
    serial_num SERIAL, 
    col1 VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    col2 VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL
 );
```

I could be wrong in so many levels about all this, but there's no one to check with, and I am learning this all by myself.

Finally, here's the `docker-compose` file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  zedb:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=user123!
      - POSTGRES_DB=fkpl
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/db-files/
    expose: 
      - 5432
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    volumes: 
      - ./db/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

  zescript:
    build: ./app 
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/scr/app
    depends_on: 
      - zedb
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running it with the same `docker-compose.yml` file on the Azure VM?

Comment: OK. No. On the Azure VM I am simply pulling it from DockerHub and `docker run`ning it with _-it_ flag (expecting it to work). So, should I clone my project repository on the Azure VM and rerun `docker-compose` from there? Is that how it works?

Comment: Yes.  The Compose setup also creates the database container and a network on which they can communicate.  I'd recommend removing the `volumes:` that mount code on to `/app` (in every environment) so that you don't need to copy the application code separately from its built image.

Comment: OK. I realized I have my fundamentals wrong about Docker and K8S and stuff, so I am going to do some more readings and video watching. Thanks for your help though.\